# Где на практике можно применить алгоритм Sliding Window в js?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Всем доброго времени суток.
Изучаю разные алгоритмы и вот дошла очередь до Sliding Window. Где его можно применить на практике в работе? Может какие-то конкретные случаи есть, кроме найти Макс. Сумму подмасива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это у олимпиадников есть классификация - есть такой-то алгоритм, можно его применить к такой-то, эдакой, да сякой задаче. И в учебниках вроде Кормена после каждой темы есть задачи - напрямую не сказано, что нужно решать с использованием только что описанных алгоритмов, но это подразумевается.

В общем случае список задач неисчерпаем, и составлять его для каждого алгоритма никто не будет. Однако изучение алгоритмов с пониманием их сути должно привести к тому, что, встретив задачу, вы можете увидеть, какой именно подход лучше применить.